# Помогите пожалуста уменшить и оптимизировать мой код

Tags: javascript, html, css

Голову ломаю, и уже не знаю, как оптимизировать код, чтоб он не повторялся, пробовал через атрибуты, функцию неправильную сложил-удалил, помогите.

HTML:

```
<div class="form__group">
                <div class="form__text">Year</div>
                  <div class="form__collapse">
                    <div class="form__collapse-from">
                      <input class="form__control" type="text" placeholder="from" id="YearFrom">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__collapse-to">
                      <input class="form__control" type="text" placeholder="to" id="YearTo">
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form__group">
                <div class="form__text">Price</div>
                <div class="form__collapse">
                  <div class="form__collapse-from">
                    <input class="form__control" type="text" placeholder="from" id="PriceFrom">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form__collapse-to">
                    <input class="form__control" type="text" placeholder="to" id="PriceTo">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

JS

```
window.onresize = function () {
  let currentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth

  let YearFrom = document.getElementById("YearFrom")
  let YearTo = document.getElementById("YearTo")

  let PriceFrom = document.querySelector("#PriceFrom")
  let PriceTo = document.querySelector("#PriceTo")

  // Year:
  //year from
  if (currentWidth < 991) {
    YearFrom = YearFrom.setAttribute("placeholder", "Year from")
  }
  else {
    YearFrom = YearFrom.setAttribute("placeholder", "from")
  }
  //year to
  if (currentWidth < 991) {
    YearTo = YearTo.setAttribute("placeholder", "Year to")
  }
  else {
    YearTo = YearTo.setAttribute("placeholder", "to")
  }

  // Price
  //price from
  if (currentWidth < 991) {
    PriceFrom = PriceFrom.setAttribute("placeholder", "Price from")
  }
  else {
    PriceFrom = PriceFrom.setAttribute("placeholder", "from")
  }
  //year to
  if (currentWidth < 991) {
    PriceTo = PriceTo.setAttribute("placeholder", "Price to")
  }
  else {
    PriceTo = PriceTo.setAttribute("placeholder", "to")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', ()=>{
    let isSmallScreen = document.documentElement.clientWidth < 991;
    
    document.getElementById("YearFrom").placeholder = isSmallScreen ? "Year from" : "from";
    document.getElementById("YearTo").placeholder = isSmallScreen ? "Year to" : "to";
    document.getElementById("PriceFrom").placeholder = isSmallScreen ? "Price from" : "from";
    document.getElementById("PriceTo").placeholder = isSmallScreen ? "Price to" : "to";
});
```

Comment: спасибо огромное